# Why my enemy not moving towards target

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here is a Video also - http://tinypic.com/r/mmagki/9

Here is my start ()  function

```
void Start()
    {

        target = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;

    }
```

and update() function

```
void Update()
    {

            transform.LookAt(target);
            float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
            distance = (transform.position - target.position).magnitude;

            //Debug.Log("Now distance -" + distance);

            if (distance < 20)
            {

                //       print("In Range");
                transform.GetComponent<Animation>().Play("attack", PlayMode.StopAll);

                if (isAttacking == false)
                {
                    isAttacking = true;
                    Hit.playerHealth -= Random.Range(20f, 25f) * Time.deltaTime;
                    Hit.playerHealth -= Random.Range(20f, 25f);
                    //   StartCoroutine(MyCoroutine(4));
                    //      print("Player Health Status = " + Hit.playerHealth);               

                    if (Hit.playerHealth <= 0)
                    {
                        //                 print("Player dead");
                    }
                }
                else
                {

                }

            }
            else
            {
                //        print("Out of Range");
                transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, step);
                transform.GetComponent<Animation>().Play("walk", PlayMode.StopAll);
            }
```

}

[image]

My Zombie (Enemy) is approaching Player, when Zombie gets hit with the wall, he should go to gate.

What i did, as soon as Zombie `(Set Trigger = checked)` hit with the wall, i have changed the  reference of 'target' to `Object with tag 'gate'`. 
Now the Zombie is not moving towards gate object (i have set tag 'gate' also). he is still moving towards player only.  Not able to change the reference of target.

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
        {
               if (col.gameObject.tag == "wall")
            {

                target = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("gate").transform;
                Debug.Log("Yes its a onTrigger Enter function , hitting with wall");
               }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have a collider on your gate. Adding a collider to the gate should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

first verify the tags of all are seted correctly, then you need to add a rigidbody component at least in one of the objects as Unity Docs say: [OnTriggerEnter](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html) . I recomend to add it to the zombie and set UseGravity to false. and with this it should work... sorry for bad english.

Comment: but with this as i can understand... your script will start attacking the gate when the distance is less to 20, to solve this you need to check if targer.tag is player.